# Authentication in yammer using PHP

Tags: php, yammer

I'm trying to authenticate into Yammer using PHP. The app is registered with the basic information. I have my client id and secret.

In the login page I place a link to https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={myclientid}&redirect={a page in my server}

When I click the link it goes to the authentication in Yammer, if I'm signed on it goes to the screen where it asks the user to link the app to his Yammer account, if not it asks user and password, so far, so good. I authorize the app.

It redirects to where its intended and I get a "code" parameter in GET.

Then I make a GET request to:

https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id={myclientid}&client_secret={mysecret}&code={code just received}

Problem is I only got the error page that reads "We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

Of course I don't get any response, or permanent token.

If I put the url directly in the browser I get the same results.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your steps looks OK to me. You may want to file a support case with microsoft if you continue to see issue, they'd need to check the status of the user account and the client ID to see if anything stands out as why you're seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't see anything wrong. I just did the same a moment ago and I got my token. The only thing I did different is that redirect url is https://www.yammer.com, as said in https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/test-token

I did all the steps of the process on the browser.

Comment: That's strange, doing it the way you say, it works, it gives me the code. Then I "paste" it into the URL parameters, and it gaves me the json with the token.

But if I do it in a program it simply doesn't work.


I don't know if this might be related to the fact that I'm not using https but http in my site (?)

Answer (score 0):

Got it…

This is quite strange, but its working now. It started working after I changed the "Redirect URI" in the registration page to https://www.yammer.com and then back to the URI in my webserver. Strange isn't it?

If somebody find this useful, I used this code (this code goes in the page after the authentication process):

```
$yammercode = $_GET["code"];

define("REDIRECT_URI", "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
define("API_KEY", "{ my API key given by Yammer}");
define("API_SECRET", "{ my API secret }");

$params = array('client_id' => API_KEY,
                'client_secret' => API_SECRET,
                'code' => $yammercode);
$url = "https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?" . http_build_query($params);
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'GET')));
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo "Response: $url<br><br>$response<br><br>";
```

Now I can extract the access token from the $response var.